# randomize or permuting values in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this: (my *real* dataframe is bigger):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), 
               B=c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
               C=c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.5))

> df
  A B   C 
1 a 1 0.1 
2 b 1 0.2 
3 c 1 0.4 
4 d 2 0.1 
5 e 2 0.5 
6 f 2 0.7 
7 g 3 0.1 
8 h 3 0.2 
9 i 3 0.5
```

I want to add several n-columns (something similar to *permutations*) where the column D would be a random value from `df$C` but this value should only be picked from those rows with the dame value of `df$B`, an example of the desired output would be:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), 
               B=c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
               C=c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.5),
               D=c(0.2,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.2))

> df
  A B   C   D
1 a 1 0.1 0.2
2 b 1 0.2 0.2
3 c 1 0.4 0.1
4 d 2 0.1 0.5
5 e 2 0.5 0.7
6 f 2 0.7 0.1
7 g 3 0.1 0.5
8 h 3 0.2 0.5
9 i 3 0.5 0.2
```

I've tried with `plyr` package but my approach does not work properly:

```
ddply(df, levels(.(B)), transform, D=sample(C))
```

I also have thought about splitting the dataframe based on `df$B` and then using a function to add the column in each dataframe using `lapply` however I have no clue how select for the levels of `df$B`,

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for **plyr**, `ave` will do the trick.

```
transform(df, D=ave(C, B, FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=TRUE)))
```

Comment: thanks @Matthew Plourde, it worked!!!, could you tell me please if `ave` function picks randomly from every value in levels of C.

Comment: Other question @Matthew Plourde, any ideas how to add n-columns to my data frame, I want to get for each row, 1000 values (randomly picked) taking in account the levels of B, perhaps a for loop? thanks for your help

Comment: `ave` applies the `sample` function to each grouping. `sample` is doing the random selection.

Comment: It's good to avoid answering separate questions in the comments. You can submit it as another question.